# use Set.fromList , get error "Prelude.!!: index too large"

Tags: haskell, ghc

There is a List `lc`

```
*Main Lib MetaDefinition WHparseCSV WHparseTxT Set> :info lc
lc :: IO [Int]  -- Defined at <interactive>:2:5
*Main Lib MetaDefinition WHparseCSV WHparseTxT Set> length <$> lc
1704399
```

I would like to know the cardinality of this list, so I tried to convert this list to a set by doing:

```
*Main Lib MetaDefinition WHparseCSV WHparseTxT Set> import Data.Set as Set
*Main Lib MetaDefinition WHparseCSV WHparseTxT Set> let sc = Set.fromList <$> lc
```

however, when I am trying to calculate the cardinality, I got the error:

```
*Main Lib MetaDefinition WHparseCSV WHparseTxT Set> length <$> sc
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

The type of `sc` is correct:

```
*Main Lib MetaDefinition WHparseCSV WHparseTxT Set> :info sc
sc :: IO (Set Int)  -- Defined at <interactive>:19:5
```

and I think `length` works well when being used to calculate the value of type `fromList ::  [Int] -> Set Int`

I really would like to know what cause this **`Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large`**.
is this because this `set` is in the `IO` monad?

Comment: The cardinality of a [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html#size) is calculated by `size` not by `length`.

Comment: @Cirquit, `length` should work as well.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are barking up the wrong tree. The definition of `length` for `Data.Set` does not use `Prelude.!!` in any way, directly or indirectly. Neither does the definition of `fromList`. I believe the definition of the list itself must involve `!!` in some fashion. Check your source, and don't use `!!`.